# Scraping YouTube - can't scrape views successfully with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriver

I'm doing a scraping project for Uni and I'm having a real hard time with some YouTube features. The main one I'm having trouble with is the views.

Inspecting the code on the actual page, I found:

```
<span dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string bold" style-target="bold">10,504 views</span>
```

So using XPATH, here's what I tried:

```
views = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-watch-metadata']")
for e in views: 
    print(e.text)
```

The results are quite strange to me (sorry, still a newbie). Here's what I got:

```
Assemblea Confindustria 2019 - Video di apertura
10K views  3 years ago
10K views  3 years ago
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't get it, and I've tried to read countless tutorials or manuals, to no avail

Comment: Your xpath is wrong. It should this format `Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']`

Comment: Also, just for future reference, make sure to add all of the code need to produce the same output you received (i.e. a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
//yt-formatted-string[@id='info']/span[1]
```